# how is lib dependence written into .dynamic section of the ELF executable in static/dynamic link case?

Tags: linux, dynamic, linker, ldd

We can use ldd to determine dependence, like:

```
 sjwang@delpe02-179: ldd `which date`
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff0f5fd000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002b2f7ea50000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b2f7ec59000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b2f7efb1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b2f7e832000)
```

Since "date" depends on "libc.so", I assume that "date" calls some function in "libc.so", and we know that ldd can determine lib dependence for "date" from .dynamic section of executable, but my question is how does compiler/linker know what should be written into .dynamic section? To be more specific:

1. If "libc.so" is statically linked with "date", then the code for this function should already be compiled into "date", so in this case "date" should not depend on "libc.so", there should be no "libc.so" in .dynamic section.
2. If "libc.so" is dynamically linked with "date", in this case, I assume that some code like this:

handle = dlopen("libc.so", ..);

should exist in "date" to load "libc.so", and "dlopen("libc.so")"  should be the only clue that "date" depends on "libc.so", in this case, how does compiler/linker know that "date" depends on "libc.so"? Does it parse all "dlopen" lines to extract lib dependence? I don't think this is a good approach, but really, is this true?

Or does compiler/linker have other methods to determine lib dependence in dynamic link case? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> how does compiler/linker know what should be written into .dynamic section

- the compiler doesn't know anything about `.dynamic` section
- the linker *knows* whether you are linking with `libc.a` or with `libc.so`. For any `*.so` that you are linking [1], it writes a `DT_NEEDED` entry into the `.dynamic` section.

> I assume that some code like this: `handle = dlopen("libc.so", ..);`

That is *incorrect* assumption and misunderstanding on your part. The `dlopen` allows you to use libraries that you do not depend on *directly* (and which may or may not be present). The libraries that you do depend on directly (such as `libc.so`):

- do not need to be dlopened (the loader will have already mapped them for you before your program starts) and
- are not optional (the loader will fail hard if they are missing).

[1] The linker flag `--as-needed` makes that statement only partially true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I agree with that for the shared libraries not depend on directly compiler only write it to .dynamic by `dlopen`. Is there other way to make it?

Answer (score 0):

There are more things in a `.so` file than just `.dynamic` sections. Read more about [Executable and Linkable Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (ELF is the format of `.so` files and of binary executables).

In particular ELF files do have headers, and these contain the information. Use the `objdump` and/or  `readelf` utilities to explore them.

Don't forget that when building a shared library, you can link it with other libraries.